# Is it possible to generate combinatoric set from a discriminated union type?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to process a discriminated union to get a combinatorics set of (the literal) values?

```
interface Foo {
  type: 'Car';
  color: 'red';
}

interface Bar {
  type: 'Car';
  color: 'blue';
}

interface Baz {
  type: 'Bike';
  color: 'yellow';
}

type Union = Foo | Bar | Baz

console.log(getCombinations<Union>())

// [
//  ['Car', 'red'],
//  ['Car', 'blue'],
//  ['Bike', 'yellow'],
// ]
```

*If possible*, this would be useful for generating test data

Comment: So you want to create actual arrays from it rather than tuple types? That can't work since types don't exist at runtime.

Comment: Yes, actual data to be used in tests. Thanks!

Comment: You can turn values into types but not types into values.